# Redirect url if it contains some set of words

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I like to htaccess redirect a url that contains some set of words to homepage

Example:

redirect

```
www.mywebsite.com/folder/dont-stop-the-fun
www.mywebsite.com/folder/dont-fun-stop-the
www.mywebsite.com/folder/play-the
www.mywebsite.com/folder/dont-fun-give-the
```

to

www.mywebsite.com/

The example above redirects any url that contains fun,play & give to homepage

I have found

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} foobar
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

but it redirects only one word

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^folder/(dont-stop-the-fun|dont-fun-stop-the|play-the|dont-fun-give-the) /index.php? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should achieve what you are looking for

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} dont-stop-the-fun [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} dont-fun-stop-the [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} play-the          [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} dont-fun-give-the
RewriteRule .* /index.php [R]
```

The above will redirect any url that contains the string anywhere in it.

e.g.  The following urls:

http://example.com/dont-fun-give-the

http://example.com/dddd/ddd/ss/aa/dont-fun-give-the

http://example.com/hello-dont-fun-give-the

http://example.com/dont-fun-give-the-dog

will all be redirected to: http://example.com/index.php